# For Loop in GNU Makefile -- Gather all Object Files into one Variable Across Mutliple Directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The general idea of what I am trying to be accomplished can hopefully be summed up by this small script.

```
DIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 ...
OBJS =

all: GENERATE_OBJECT_FILES

GENERATE_OBJECT_FILES: 
        for curr_dir in $(DIRS); \
        do \
                $(join $(OBJS), `ls $${curr_dir}/*.o`); \
        done

        echo $(OBJS);
```

How could I accomplish this with a script within a Makefile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) outside the recipe, like this:

```
DIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 ...
OBJS := $(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.o))

all : $(OBJS)
    @echo $^
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it this way:

```
DIRS = dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 ...
OBJS = $(wildcard $(DIRS:=/*.o))

GENERATE_OBJECT_FILES:
    @echo $(OBJS);
```

Comment: Good grief and to think that I had to look for the 'for' loop to find this answer...thank you so much, I was beginning to question my sanity. A side question, is there any way to set a variable inside of a for-loop?

Comment: @ATaylor: Yes. Could you be more specific? A shell `for` loop like Matthem Hoggan's, or a Make `foreach` look like Eldar Abusalimov's? What do you want to do with the variable?

Comment: Generally I wanted to use a regular `for`-loop, which expands a variable. Something like `for i in $(LIST) ; do Var += $$i ; done` It kept refusing me, telling me that `Var` didn't exist.

Comment: @ATaylor: That command contains a syntax error which you will discover if you *simplify*. Try running the loop without Make. Then try executing the command without the loop. Then fix it, decide whether it does what you actually have in mind, and work back up.